# I want to post a limit on a IP for max open connection at a single time.

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I am using web-logic.
I want to post a limit on user(IP) so that they (a perticular IP) can't open more than 10 (a specific number) connection at a time.
Please suggest :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41069_01/Platform.11-0/ATGInstallGuide/html/s1605oracleweblogicipfiltering01.html

Comment: Please do some more research and post details, this question is too broad to understand what you need